# InvalidArgument with SelectionStart when handling backspace

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Just starting out in C#. I've had some success in creating a simple text editor in Windows Forms, that loads a text file into a Read Only, rich text box. If I choose to edit the file using a "Edit" button, then Form2 pops up and allows me to append or delete characters.
The problem I am having is if the cursor is at the beginning of the text file and I press the backspace button that I made, I get an exception "InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'SelectionStart'."
I have tried many things and after a whole day of trying different things, I'm left to wonder what can be done to resolve this.

```
        private void button32_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     //BackSpace button
    {

        int index = richTextBox.SelectionStart - 1;
        richTextBox.SelectionStart = index;
        if (richTextBox.Text.Length < 1) MessageBox.Show("  Nothing to Undo  ");

            //Otherwise, delete character when button press, (one character at a time).
        else

       richTextBox.Text = richTextBox.Text.Remove(richTextBox.SelectionStart - 1, 1);
      richTextBox.Focus();
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the cursor is placed at the beginning of the text, value of `index` becomes `-1` and that is not a valid value for `SelectionStart`. Note that you need to ignore the backspace button at that position because there is nothing to remove there. So simply use an `if`:

```
private void button32_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        int index = richTextBox.SelectionStart - 1;
        if (richTextBox.Text.Length > 0 && index >= 0)
        {
            richTextBox.SelectionStart = index;

            richTextBox.Text = richTextBox.Text.Remove(index, 1);
            richTextBox.SelectionStart = index;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("  Nothing to Undo  ");
        richTextBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: After altering my code to your suggestion, the exception went away, but the MessageBox never shows up when the cursor is back at the beginning of line 1(with nothing left to remove), and the focus/cursor is no longer flashing in the RichTextBox.

Comment: OK. The code was unclear about the messagebox, so you want it to display if the cursor if at the beginning of the first line?

Comment: Yes preferably. Thanks for the help.